# Shared, global object instances - where should they "live"?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

What options exist in instances where you genuinely want a single instance of an object, shared and persistent through all requests?

My current conclusion is that I'll have to implement a Singleton pattern - so access this object statically, use some careful locking, and otherwise just ensure that the server is running only one worker process.

Am I missing anything? Does ASP.Net make any specific allowance for this kind of thing?

For context;
I have an application which'll be a front-end to a lot of data stored in-memory (it's a game; so the data is game state for a number of games in-progress). The games are short-lived, so keeping them in memory seems to make more sense that serializing the data anywhere, but I'll need some static "registry" for the data.

Comment: In ASP, your application can recycle at any time, for various reasons. Do you want to *lose* all state during such a recycle? If not, then no, you don't want an in memory singleton, and you need to look at what durable storage options will work for you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Really appreciate the heads up on this. Worker process recycling is ultimately an IIS feature, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [`Application` collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) that you could use to access an object from any user. However, it wouldn't simplify much in your case. You wouldn't need a singleton, but similar code to access it, and you still need to synchronise the access.

You might also consider if you really want to keep everything only in memory, considering that all current games would vanish if the application was recycled (which it is daily by default). You might want to persist the state somewhere less volatile, and only keep a copy in memory for fast access. Then the [`Cache` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be of interest.

Comment: Thanks, Guffa. I'm investigating a more stateless architecture but I'm still interested in this more stateful route. Do you know; is the application pool recycling just a defensive measure against "programmer error", or do ASP.Net programs inherently need "rebooting" after a while?

Comment: @ledneb: Well, I would say a little bit of both. There are some parts of the framework that could cause problems if used in a certain way in an application running for a long time. If you for example are interning strings, then the collection of interned strings will keep growing with every new string that is found, until it runs out of memory. If you write an application that should be able survive for a long time, you need a lot of knowledge of the framework implementation to avoid certain things. Recycling lowers the demands on the application robustness to a more reasonable level.